# Is there a google app engine plug-in for Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans-7

Is there a google app engine plug-in for Netbeans 7.3? I keep finding old links for previous version(all links are not working) but I cannot find a new version of the plugin anywhere.

I am looking to create a java-based google app engine project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try here: https://code.google.com/p/nb-gaelyk-plugin/downloads/list
It's a fixed clone from kenai 
The source code: https://github.com/Valery-Sh/NbAppEngine

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do you have a serious GAE/J app in production made with this plugin?

Comment: No, not at that/this time. I was researching IDEs for the production one, and had already been familiar with Netbeans (7.3 at the time of the original post).