# Add Google App Engine server plug-in in netbean 7.3

Tags: java, netbeans, jsf-2

I am using netbeans 7.3 to deploy my jsf application in GAE. I am now trying to add a server from plugin. [This is described in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492669/is-there-a-google-app-engine-plug-in-for-netbeans-7-3).

I tried to install six .nbm-types files which are in nbappengine-7.3-gae1.8.x.zip file:

1. org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine.nbm
2. org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-deployment.nbm
3. org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-editor.nbm
4. org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-hints.nbm
5. org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-kit.nbm
6. org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-samples.nbm

All files are installed except:

- org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-kit.nbm (Google App Engine Support)
- org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine.nbm (Google App Engine Server)

[image: ScreenShot]

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the error message that your IDE is giving you. Please take minute to look at the image that you included in your post; it contains the answers you need. The plugins you are trying to install have dependencies that are unmet. Install the plugins that it asks for. The text in the image you provided is common in computer programming - often a message will come that says:

> X software requires Y software version >= 0.9.14, only 0.3.10 found.

This means you need to upgrade to a higher version (>= 0.9.14) for Y before X can be installed, since it requires it. This is known as a "dependency" since X *depends on* Y.